# How to customize Selenium test error/fail message

Tags: visual-studio-2012, selenium, ui-testing, nosuchelementexception

I'm using VS2012 and i want to customize my selenium tests.

For example, when test fails, i want to show the text `The page loaded too long - unable to login + original message` instead of showing only this: `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == loginElementID`. Is it possible? How and when to use Assertions when UI testing?
That would make my tests more understandable and informative.

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 8));
wait.Message = "Page Loaded too long";
```

Or how to show wait.Message when test fails ?

Comment: Are you using a framework that provides logging to file or are you just talking about changing the output in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve there are at least two ways of doing it (and probably more).

1. Use try..catch statement. Catch NoSuchElementException and throw new one with your own message. One way of doing it would be wrapping WebDriver with your own class and then wrapping each method (findBy, get) with try..catch.
2. Use EventFiringWebDriver with WebDriverEventListener and implement proper logging in onError method.