# Selenium IDE Custom error messages

Tags: error-handling, selenium-ide

I have read this ([How to customize Selenium test error/fail message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18249035/how-to-customize-selenium-test-error-fail-message)) question and it gave me some hope but can this be done with selenium IDE also? My boss wants to automate all tests but wants to keep it simple for non programmers to use so I cannot use WebDriver or jUnit.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and came out with a surprisingly amusing answer. Selenium will write a failure only upon stepping on an error. In the current case I wanted Selenium to warn me if the 'Log In' button was absent on my page but a gotoIf wasn't going to do the job alone. Therefore I forced Selenium into an error by writing a click command that didn't exist 'TestLoginB2B failed because the login button was' and using it as my custom error line as Selenium will mention the name of a failed click command and always write them in red therefore allowing my file logging addon to spot them.

Custom error message

[image]